# flag to select/unselect a <mat-option>

Tags: angular, angular-material

In this example:

```
<mat-select multiple>
    <mat-option>Option 1</mat-option>
    <mat-option>Option 2</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Is there a flag in mat-option to say "selected/unselected" ? I ask this because i would like to select/unselect an option with a button later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using multiple select, choose between reactive form or template-driven approach...if you are using reactive form then

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>MultiSelect</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="multiControl" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">{{option}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<button (click)="deselectOption()">click me</button>
```

TYPESCRIPT:

```
multiControl = new FormControl();
options = [
'option1',
'option2'
];
deselectOption() {
// if you want to remove 'option1'
const alteredArray = this.multiControl.value.filter((option) => {
      return option!== 'option1';
    });
    this.multiControl.setValue(alteredArray);
}
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

From the material api [mat-select](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview):

The sligthly modified component.ts:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'select-multiple-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-multiple-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['select-multiple-example.css'],
  })
export class SelectMultipleExample implements OnInit {
  toppings = new FormControl(['Extra cheese']);
  toppingList: string[] = ['Extra cheese', 'Mushroom', 'Onion', 'Pepperoni','Sausage', 'Tomato'];
 }
```

and the html:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<p>{{toppings.value}}</p>
```

mat select multiple allows mor than one option to be selected.
and via the formcontrol you can start with one or more selected from the beginning

Stackblitz: https://angular-azjefx.stackblitz.io/

Comment: Yes but if i want to unselect the option 3 (in your example 'Onion') with a button. How i unselect ONLY this option ?

Comment: automatically. Wait i'll provide a stackblitz

Comment: You can also change the value outside of the mat select by changing the value of the formcontrol